# Subsetting and Grouping a variable in Dataframe keeping the name of the rows

Tags: r

I have this data set, and as you see I subset it and group it by the variable x.

```
x<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5)
y<-c(30,30,30,30,30,30,44,30,55,30,30,90,30,30,30,30,30,49,30,30,30,30,30,50)
data<-cbind(x,y)
data<-as.data.frame(data)
data<-subset(data,y<=30)
data
Data1<-data %>%

group_by(data$x) %>%

summarise( sum(y,na.rm = T))
Data1
```

The thing is that when it groups I want it to keep the rows that it subsets I want to know the exact rows that the grouping and subseting happened
The preferred out put would be

```
 number of rows data$x sum(y, na.rm = T)
1,2,3,4,5,6      1               180
8,10             2                60
11,13,14         3                90
15,16,17,19      4               120
20,21,22,23      5               120
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a helpful function called `rownames_to_column` we can use.

```
data %>%
    rownames_to_column() %>%
    group_by(x) %>%
    summarise(rn_list = paste0(rowname, collapse = ","),
              sum_y = sum(y, na.rm = TRUE))

      x rn_list     sum_y
1     1 1,2,3,4,5,6   180
2     2 8,10           60
3     3 11,13,14       90
4     4 15,16,17,19   120
5     5 20,21,22,23   120
```

Also note that we do not need to use `group_by(data$x)`, since we're using `%>%` we can just use `group_by(x)`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, .(rn_list = toString(.I), sum_y = sum(y, na.rm = TRUE)), .(x)]
#   x          rn_list sum_y
#1: 1 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6   180
#2: 2             7, 8    60
#3: 3        9, 10, 11    90
#4: 4   12, 13, 14, 15   120
#5: 5   16, 17, 18, 19   120
```